# Converting an XML file to a multi-dimensional dictionnary

Tags: c#, xml, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to import XML files into my C# code.

I would like to access these data like a dictionnary element.

Example:

```
// XML:

<root>
    <node>
        <value1>
        </value1>
        <value2>
            <properties>
            </properties>
        </value2>
        <randomnode>
            <blabla>X</blabla>
        </randomnode>
    </node>
</root>

// C#:
values["root"]["node"]["randomnode"]["blabla"] == "X" // true
```

Is there any way to do this?
As far as I've searched, I could only get a dictionnary using XElements, but it was only 2-dimensions and I had to specify names and values as attributes in the XML file.

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `dynamic` type for this. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/436406/Power-of-Dynamic-Reading-XML-and-CSV-files-made-ea) for code. Or [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

I've used sharpSerializer for that. Heres a pretty good walkthrough: 
[XML Serialization of Generic Dictionary, Multidimensional Array, and Inherited Type, with sharpSerializer .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76530/XML-Serialization-of-Generic-Dictionary-Multidimen)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with serialization is the fact that you need to know what your XML will looks like before getting the datas, which I don't.